# 7z archive created with command lines is not the same as the one created with 7z GUI

Tags: batch-file, command-line, drag-and-drop, 7zip, archiving

Drag-n-drop files and folders to create 7z archive with following settings:
Archive: a.7z
Archive Format: 7z
Compression level: Ultra
Compression method: LZMA
Dictionary size: 64MB
Word size: 64
Solid Block Size: Solid

---

Q1: Is the following code the same as the above settings?

```
:addto7z
7za a -t7z "%~dp1a.7z" -m0=lzma:d=64m -mx=9 "%1"
shift
if "%~1" == "" goto:end
goto:addto7z
:end
```

Q2: The archive size is larger than the one created with 7-Zip GUI.
How can I fix it?

```
---------------------------    ---------------------------
Created with command lines     Created with GUI
---------------------------    ---------------------------
Size: 10 022 305               Size: 10 022 305
Packed Size: 3 541 483         Packed Size: 3 529 578
Folders: 6                     Folders: 6
Files: 49                      Files: 49
CRC: 0C621D8E                  CRC: 0C621D8E
---------------------------    ---------------------------
Path: a.7z                     Path: a.7z
Type: 7z                       Type: 7z
Physical Size: 3 542 807       Physical Size: 3 530 837
Headers Size: 1 324            Headers Size: 1 259
Method: LZMA:23 BCJ2           Method: LZMA:12m BCJ2
Solid: +                       Solid: +
Blocks: 6                      Blocks: 2
---------------------------    ---------------------------
```

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Comment: @SomethingDark, it does not work if I drag-n-drop more than 1 item to the batch file.

Comment: Well, if you don't use a `for` loop to iterate over `%*`, it's not going to.

Comment: For the `for` loop problem, I use a different approach as I found an old script. But it is different to the way that `7zG` compresses multiple items, thus the compress size is a bit larger than the one that `7zG` compresses. How do I fix it?

Comment: Do you want all of the passed-in files to be in one large archive, or should each file be in its own separate archive?

Comment: It has to be `compress to a single archive` as there is no `compress to separate archives` option in `7zG`. So my problem is that the archives created with the batch file and `7zG` have different size. Can it be fixed?